# Navigation Controller en IOS , swift

Tags: ios, swift

estoy tratando de conseguir este desafio: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U5ozYLO4KVs&t=978s pero no consigo sacar el Navigation Controller, lo he colocado tal cual en el video pero no funciona creo que debo hacerlo de otra forma, alguna sugerencia?
minuto: 19:27

mi codigo:
`ya fui a mainSB/ editor / embed in /navigation controller y agregue :`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Borrar Todos",style: .done, target: presenter, action: #selector(presenter.removeAll))
```

tambien le coloque el `@objc` al metodo `RemoveAll`, que necesito para que mi compilador coloque el boton "Borrar todos", en mi interfaz?

Comment: En el storyboard si se creó el `navigation controller`? Intentaste compilar quitando los elementos y los constraints? Es decir compilar el proyecto solo con el `navigation button`.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda! Segui tus sugerencias y he podido resolver el problema. Resulta que el Navigation Controller estaba correctamente configurado en el Storyboard, pero algunas subvistas estaban ocultando el botón de navegación. Después de comentar esas subvistas, el botón apareció correctamente. Gracias de nuevo por tu asistencia.